# How to upload image file into the database

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, image-uploading

I couldn't handle with inserting image file into the database. I could write a code snippet related with inserting process in the controller part.

I could use `base64encode` process for image.

I could define image as a `byte` part because I define image as `Blob` in the database part.

How can I do the process if it isn't right.

Controller part

```
@PostMapping("/saveCustomer") // @RequestMapping(path = "/saveCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer,@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) {

        System.out.println("/saveCustomer | File Name : "+file.getName());


        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int) file.getSize()];

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getOriginalFilename());
            fileInputStream.read(imageBytes);
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        theCustomer.setImage(imageBytes);


        // save the customer using our service
        customerService.saveCustomer(theCustomer);


        return "redirect:/customer/list";
    }
```

Customer class

```
    public class Customer implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name="CUSTOMER_SEQ", sequenceName="CUSTOMER_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CUSTOMER_SEQ")
        @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
        private int id;

        @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name="LASTNAME")
        private String lastName;

        @Column(name="EMAIL")
        private String email;

        @Column(name="IMAGE")
        private byte[] image;

        @Transient
        private String base64Image;

public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

public String getBase64Image() {
        base64Image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(this.image);
        return base64Image;
    }

    public void setBase64Image(String base64Image) {
        this.base64Image = base64Image;
    }

    ...
    }
```

html part

```
<tr>
    <td>Image:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="photo" required="required"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the community project called [Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content).

This project provides an abstraction over various different types of storage for Spring Resources.

It provides a programming model very similar to Spring Data and therefore you get a lot of boilerplate implementation for free.  There is no need to define your own controller implementation for example.

There are getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-rest-docs/) and examples for various different databases [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples/tree/master/spring-eg-content-jpa).  A combination of spring-content-jpa and spring-content-rest will be enough.  There is also a good example answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268541/how-to-stream-large-blob-from-database-to-application-using-jpa/57299082#57299082).